# Conjoint analysis or discrete choice analysis ? And which software?

Tags: discrete-data, conjoint-analysis

Suppose I would like to model the light-bulb preference of respondents.
I would like to ask their preferences between existing bulbs on the market. And when you choose a bulb in a shop you usually see a package with many information gathered togheter such as:

- technology (halo, fluo, led)
- price
- energy label EURO norm (from E to A++)
- shape (pear, candle, spiral, steam)
- watts.
- brand (philips,osram , etc)

As there are too many combination respondents should only see max three combinations and check [i said check NOT rate...] the one they prefer (of course many iterations are needed per respondent to understand how he choose his bulb)
At the end, respondent should also give socio-demo infos such as.

- Gender
- Age
- Income

I would like to see the global effect of attribute. Like what's in general the most important criteria to choose a bulb.
I would like to get a kind of econometrical analysis to know if there is difference of choice between the socio demo infos.

I've heard about conjoint analysis or discrete choice analysis methods. 
**In my case which one would be more appropiate?**

Which software(s) would also be more appropriate for the overall process (from the design to the analyis)?

Comment: Hello, while I am nox expert on both methods I can say that market research does a lot of such questions and mostly uses conjoint analysis for it.
If you are unsure, I would recommend consulting the book http://www.amazon.de/Using-Multivariate-Statistics-Barbara-Tabachnick/dp/0205465250. It contains excellent "when to use method [x] " texts which are really helpful to decide such questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few packages in R, such as described in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43544/off-the-shelf-conjoint-analysis-software). You would probably need to used a hierarchical Bayes model for this, so the package `bayesm` would be required.

Another way would be to use off-the-shelf SaaS software, such as [Conjoint.ly](https://conjoint.ly/), which can handle the required task.